# Calling an int that gets changed in another class

Tags: java, android, class, int, call

Here's the problem, I have a class (lets say class1) where depending on the button you select int x is changed to a number 1-6. I need to be able to call this int in class 2, but it does not read the new int x value, it only reads the default.

```
public class class1 extends Activity {
    private view btn1;
    private view btn2;
    //...
    private view btn6;
    public int x = 1;

btn1.setOnClickListener(sbtn1Listener);
//...
btn2.setOnClickListener(sbtn2Listener);

private View.OnClickListener sbtn1Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        x = 1;
    }
};
private View.OnClickListener sbtn2Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        x = 2;
    }
};
//...
```

So the buttons work fine in that program, there's more to it but I'll just leave it at that for now. Then class2 needs to read the new value.

```
public class class2 extends BaseObject {
    public int y = 1;

    class1 a = new class1();
    a.getx();

    y = a;

    if (y == 1) {
    }else if (y == 2){
    //...
```

Instead of reading the new x value from class1 it only reads the default set as 1.

Also note that I cannot change the extended part of class2 because BaseObject is neccessary for it to run all it's components.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because class2 is creating a new instance of class 1.

What you need to do is access the already existing instance of class 1.

If you globalise class two, and then set it via class 1 you will be able to access it.

```
public class class1 extends Activity {
private view btn1;
private view btn2;
//...
private view btn6;
public int x = 1;
public class2 cls2; // SET GLOBAL. Needs initialising somewhere relevant.

btn1.setOnClickListener(sbtn1Listener);
//...
btn2.setOnClickListener(sbtn2Listener);

private View.OnClickListener sbtn1Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    x = 1;
    cls2.x = 1; // Or use setter methods in class 2.
}
};
private View.OnClickListener sbtn2Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    x = 2;
    cls2.x = 2;
}
};
```

Then in class 2 have a public variable called x. (the one you are setting in the click listeners.

Important: where ever you call class 2, make sure you assign it as the global instance, and not a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `int x a static variable.`

**Eg:**

```
public static int x = 1;
```

Now access it from another class like this...

```
int y = class1.x;
```

// This will reflect the changed x value.